# Canvas Animation - Stuck

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to get to grips with canvas animation.  I came across a great tutorial at http://www.kirupa.com/html5/creating_simple_html5_canvas_animation.htm (props!!) but I am trying to take this a little further by included user interaction, in the form of an input to specify the centre of the circle (I refer to it as "width" in the below code).

What I have tried is below and it works, to a certain degree.  You will see the centre of the circle starts at 175.  When I input anything above this, the circle does move to the right, as it should according to my code.  I can then enter any number less than the current point and it will move to the left, as it should.

However!!  After I have input the first figure, whether it be less or more than the start point, I then try to enter a figure larger than the current point and the circle just disappears.

I am baffled and after an explanation for why this is happening and a possible solution...  if possible.

Thanks in advance, the code I have is...

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                       window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                       window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                       window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var start = 175;
var startH = 250;
var radius = 175;

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.arc(start, startH, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.fillStyle = "#006699";
ctx.fill();

function drawCircle() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;

    if(start == width) {
        start = width;          

    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);

        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.arc(start, startH, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.fillStyle = "#006699";
        ctx.fill();

        if(start < width) {
            start += 1;
        } else {
            start -= 1;
        }

        requestAnimFrame(drawCircle);

    }

}
```

Comment: `width` is the value of an input field, right? But `start` needs to be a number and `width` is a string… something will surely go wrong that way.

Comment: Thanks Xufox!  I've used Number(document.getElementById("width").value); and that works perfectly.  Why is it always something so simple?!

Comment: Example: `start == width` will return `true` when `60 == '60'` but `start = width` will make `start` a string and any `start += 1` afterwards will return `'601'`, `'6011'`, etc.

Comment: Oh, that was the problem? Posting as answer!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too.  That makes sense now!  Adding the 1 on the end was pushing it off my canvas, hence the disappearing act!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: convert the string to a number:

```
var width = Number(document.getElementById("width").value);
```

---

**Explanation**: let’s examine the *types* in the code:

An input’s value will always be a *string*:

```
width = document.getElementById("width").value;
```

This equality operator disregards the type: `60 == '60'` is as true as `60 == 60`:

```
start == width
```

Only `===` will take the type into account as well. Next, the `<` operator implicitly converts any string into a number when comparing numbers with numbers as strings: `'60' < 62` is true, `'60' < 58` is false:

```
start < width
```

Next up, we’ve got an assignment that adds (or subtracts) `1` to `start`. This is not an issue as long as `start` is a number:

```
start += 1
```

And at some point `start == width` will become true and then this horrible thing happens:

```
start = width
```

From now on `start` is a *string*, because *so is `width`*. `==` will still work, `<` will still work, but…

```
start += 1
```

This will attempt to add a string and a number. Because JavaScript’s result of such an operation is always a *string* it will instead *implicitly convert the number into a string* and thus perform a string *concatenation*: `'60' + 1 === '601'`. Repeat this a few times and you end up with `'6011111111111111111111111111111'` and so on.

To prevent this from happening, refer to the solution at the top of this answer: convert the string to a number first.